# Save Image from Memorystream using C# and ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a memory stream to resize an image through a FileUpload control. After it resizes it I want it to save to my filesystem at `"~/images/2012/" + filename`.

How do I save the image from a memorystream?

```
System.Drawing.Image imageLarge = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
System.Drawing.Image imageLarge1 = ResizeImage(imageLarge, 200, 300);

MemoryStream memolarge = new MemoryStream();
imageLarge1.Save(memolarge, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
System.Drawing.Image returnImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memolarge);

Encoder myEncoder;
EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter;
EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters;
myEncoder = Encoder.Quality;
myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 100L);
myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;

string convertedImage = returnImage.ToString();
returnImage.Save("~/images/2012/" + filename, 
    ImageFormat.Jpeg, myEncoderParameters);
```

This is the error I am getting along with an overloaded method error:

> cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat' to System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo

Answer (score 4):

Look at the overloads of [`Image.Save`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ex6sdew.aspx).

Only the final two accept `EncoderParameters`, and neither of them accept an `ImageFormat` - both accept an `ImageCodecInfo`.

It's very important to be able to diagnose this kind of problem yourself:

- Look at the compiler error *carefully*
- Read the documentation
- Check whether the call you're making makes sense

This has nothing to do with saving to a `MemoryStream` in particular - in fact, it's not clear why you're saving an `Image` and then immediately loading an `Image` from the same stream. (I'd advise setting the `Position` to 0 before you do so anyway, if you really want to keep doing this.)

Answer (score 2):

Try this line instead:

```
returnImage.Save(
    "~/images/2012/" + filename,
    ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()
        .Where(i => i.MimeType == "image/jpeg")
        .First(),
    myEncoderParameters);
```

Comment: When I use this code it gives me this error
"Use of unassigned local variable 'myEncoderParameters'
Any idea what that means? I tried googling it but I am at best an ametur coder and I'm not getting it.

Answer (score 0):

See post [Saving as jpeg from memorystream in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661967/saving-as-jpeg-from-memorystream-in-c-sharp)  it does something very similar to what you are looking for.

Also to change the codec properly
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ytz20d80.aspx